# How can I hid S3 and CloudFront contents?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an S3 bucket and Cloud Front distribution to deliver assets (PDF files) to my site and CMS.  I want users to be able to access the PDF, but

I noticed that if I use either the S3 or Could Front URLs that I can erase the file name (e.g., `my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/file.pdf` or `cloudfront-domain-name/file.pdf`) and see an XML tree of the S3 or Cloud Front that displays all the content (filenames of all the PDFs, and the S3 URL in the case of the CloudFront URL).

How can I prevent somebody from doing this?

Answer (score 0):

make the bucket not open to public, the it wont list the contents in the bucket

[image]

Comment: but then how do they view the individual asset assigned to the page they are viewing?

Comment: Make the individual asset public, instead of the whole bucket.